# How to get the user euid given his name in LDAP?

Tags: python, ldap

I'm trying to use LDAP with Python. Given a `username`, is it possible to find his euid (Effective user ID)? I could not find an example in the docs of LDAP. I want to use something similar to the `id` command in Linux which gives me the Effective user ID of the user.

Comment: Is your username different from the user id somehow?

Comment: @marcdtheking yes, the username is a name and the id is a string of digits.